# Custom SVG progress bar fill

Tags: animation, svg, webkit, progress-bar

In its simplest form, I want to make a loading page like [this website](http://www.tilljanz.com).

I want to use a custom SVG logo (that I have made in illustrator) and horizontally fill the logo as the page loads.

Like a SVG clip mask progress bar (or something).

Please, please help me!

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do this is with a gradient fill.

```
<linearGradient id="progress">
   <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
   <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="grey"/>
</linearGradient>
```

You just need to change the value of `offset` on both `<stop>` elements to be the percentage you want - either 0->1 or "0%"->"100%".  For example:

An example function might be:

```
function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}
```

This approach works for any SVG element, whether it be text, as in the demo below, or a complicated logo made of paths.

```js
function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}

  
// Simple test of setProgress().
// We step up from 0 to 1 using timeouts
val = 0;
doTimeout();

function doTimeout() {
  setProgress(val);
  val += 0.01;
  if (val <= 1) {
    setTimeout(doTimeout, 30);
  }
}
```

```css
text {
  font: 'Times Roman', serif;
  font-size: 125px;
  fill: url(#progress);
}
```

```html
<svg width="650" height="150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="progress">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="grey"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text x="20" y="120">TILL JANZ</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Feel like I'm close... [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jon1988/x6m6doop/4/)

Cant make it fill the SVG as one object and it also stops a little short of the end.

Comment: It needs to be one path. So the simplest solution for you is to just concatenate the two `d` attributes together in one path.  https://jsfiddle.net/x6m6doop/8/

Comment: The problem with it not finishing was just an issue with the test timeout loop not getting to "1.0".  It shouldn't affect you if you are just calling `setProgress()` from your code. Here's a fixed fiddle anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/x6m6doop/9/

Comment: Amazing! I tried to test it as a progress bar. I added a high res image and uploaded it here... [jonparkinson.co.uk/mustard/](http://jonparkinson.co.uk/mustard/). Doesn't seam to be loading as the page loads. Is it only on a set time? Thanks for all your help so far, honestly, really appreciate it.

Comment: The test timeout loop I added was just to show the progress bar in action.  It lasts a fixed 3 seconds or so.  In a real scenario, you would call the `setProgress()` function after each step in your initialisation.  For example, if you had to load five big images, you would call `setProgress(0)` at the start, then `setProgress(0.2)` after the first image, then `setProgress(0.4)` after the next, etc.

Comment: Is there no a way of setting it so it loads as the **whole** page loads? That way no matter how many images I have I don't have to update it?

Comment: No. There is no way to ask the browser how far through the whole load process it is.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you show me how I would call the `setProgress()` after each step, like you were describing before. That'd really help me out. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi, I want to load 9 images, could you do me a quick jsfiddle for this? I have no idea what I'm doing! Thanks in advanced... life saver!

Comment: I don't know how you are loading your images, or for what purpose, so I can't answer your question.  Once each image is loaded (for example in an `<img>` onLoad event handler), call `setProgress()` with an appropriate percentage.  For example after the seventh image call `setProgress(7/9)`.

Comment: Hi, How can I fill color upto half image with animation?

Comment: @PathikVejani See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801976/custom-svg-progress-bar-fill/30802965#30802965  Just have it stop at 0.5 (50%) instead of 1 (100%)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau in which part I have to make changes? Can you pls guide me?

Comment: Change `if (val <= 1) {` to `if (val <= 0.5) {`

Comment: Having troubles applying this to a `<embed src="path/to/logo.svg>`. Is there anything I need to be careful of?