# How to dynamically apply multiple CSS webkit annimations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, css-animations

Pulling my hair out on this one.  I have a 5 star rating system for products in my app and I am having a heck of a time trying to get the right CSS animations to apply to the one star that shows the partial coloring.

Example: rating is 3.3, three fully colored stars, then the 4th star would only be 30% colored

I am trying to apply partial color to the 4th star using CSS -webkit animations but every technique I am using doesn't work or has some issue.

Star Icons:

```
  <div class="" style="font-size:14px;">
    <i class="ion-ios-star" id="Rating_{{prod.prodID}}_1" ></i>
    <i class="ion-ios-star" id="Rating_{{prod.prodID}}_2" ></i>
    <i class="ion-ios-star" id="Rating_{{prod.prodID}}_3" ></i>
    <i class="ion-ios-star" id="Rating_{{prod.prodID}}_4" ></i>
    <i class="ion-ios-star" id="Rating_{{prod.prodID}}_5" ></i>
    {{prod.Rating}} out of {{prod.RatingCount}} reviews
  </div>
```

Statically, applying the `ratingStarA` class to my element works, all of the attributes are there, even if they are crossed out leaving only the valid ones to make the animation work:

```
.ratingStarA {
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 30%, #a742c6 70%); 
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 30%,#a742c6 70%); 
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e72c83 30%,#a742c6 70%);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}

.ratingStarB {
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
```

But I need to dynamically apply the `background` because I need to pass in the percent values and this where things get wonky.  The `-webkit-background-clip` style is the one that seems to be causing all the problems.  So far, any method I have tried to use to apply it dynamically fails.

METHOD A: this seemingly works, but the 'background' is crossed out and the '-webkit-background-clip' is missing when I inspect the element...**BUT**...the animation is working - I just don't trust it or understand why this is happening.

```
function colorStars(ID,rating) {
    // for the partial star, rating is passed in as ".3"
    var colorPer = rating * 100 ;
    var whitePer = 100 - colorPer ;
    var star = document.getElementById(ID) ;

    star.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(right," +eColors.orange+ " " +colorPer+ "%, lightgray " +whitePer+ "%)" ;
    star.style['webkit-background-clip'] = "text" ;
    star.style['webkit-text-fill-color'] = "transparent" ;
}
```

METHOD B: just setting the background and then apply a class, but all the '-xxx-background-clip' are missing from the element after the class is applied and thus the partial star is not visible.

```
function colorStars(ID,rating) {
    // for the partial star, rating is passed in as ".3"
    var colorPer = rating * 100 ;
    var whitePer = 100 - colorPer ;
    var star = document.getElementById(ID) ;

    star.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(right," +eColors.orange+ " " +colorPer+ "%, lightgray " +whitePer+ "%)" ;
    start.classList.add('ratingStarB') ;
}
```

METHOD C: How to apply multiple backgrounds for cross browser support?  I can't apply multiple backgrounds dynamically, like in a class,  because the last one overwrites the first two

```
function colorStars(ID,rating) {
    // for the partial star, rating is passed in as ".3"
    var colorPer = rating * 100 ;
    var whitePer = 100 - colorPer ;
    var star = document.getElementById(ID) ;

    star.style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(right," +eColors.orange+ " " +colorPer+ "%, lightgray " +whitePer+ "%)" ;
    star.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(right," +eColors.orange+ " " +colorPer+ "%, lightgray " +whitePer+ "%)" ;

    // because this is the last 'background' applied, it overwrites the first two
    star.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right," +eColors.orange+ " " +colorPer+ "%, lightgray " +whitePer+ "%)" ;

    //as well, only the '-webkit-text-fill-color' is applied, the others are not there.
    star.style['-moz-background-clip'] = "text" ;
    star.style['-webkit-background-clip'] = "text" ;
    star.style['background-clip'] = "text" ;
    star.style['-webkit-text-fill-color'] = "transparent" ;
}
```

Again, Method A seems to work, but viewing the elements shows the styles crossed out or missing - and it doesn't support cross browser support.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of tag is each star ?

Comment: @Xanthous updated OP....they are icons.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using masking inside a SVG element and a little *javascript* found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802965/9526947)

```js
function setProgress(amt) {
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}

let val = 0;

function colorStars() {
  const rating = 2.65,      // usually dynamic value
    flatten = rating / 5;  // to fit within 0-1 range

  setProgress(val);
  val += 0.01;
  if (val <= flatten) {
    setTimeout(colorStars, 30);
  }
}
```

```css
body { display: flex; align-items: center; gap: 1rem }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 24" width="120" height="24">
  <g mask="url(#mask)">
    <path id="star" d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" />

    <use xlink:href="#star" x="24" y="0" />
    <use xlink:href="#star" x="48" y="0" />
    <use xlink:href="#star" x="72" y="0" />
    <use xlink:href="#star" x="96" y="0" />
  </g>

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="progress" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="lightblue" />
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>

    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="120" height="100" fill="url(#progress)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<button onclick="colorStars()">Color Stars</button>
```